# Using ng-model on object in ng-repeat does update origin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to update both the key and the value of an object from within an ng-repeat using the template engine in angular. This does not seem to work, however.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <input data-ng-model="key" />
    <input data-ng-model="value" />
</div>
```

In this example, the text field is typeable, and you can change the value of key and value inside the ng.repeat scope, but these values are not updated on the original object! Why is this? How can I solve this without having to make some nasty hack in javascript?

I made a jsfiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/xkg8den8/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ng-repeat` creates a child scope and you are not using the golden rule of always passing an object to `ng-model`.

Because you are passing primitives within a child scope, you have broken the 2 way binding to the object since there is no inheritance for primitives.

Changing the `key` in your objects doesn't make sense but for the values you can do

```
<input data-ng-model="data[key]" />
```

These issues are fundamental to how angular works and to prototypical inheritance. There is lots written about how scopes work...it will definitely be worth your time to research this

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkg8den8/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: also, the practice of using `ng-init` rather than a controller is counter to it's intended purpose, and can have unintended side effects as well.

Comment: Sure, but using your method one can only update the value of the object. I would also like the user to be able to update the keys. So what you're basically telling me is that there is no way to do this without involving some hackery in a controller?

Comment: Updating keys makes no sense. What would use case be for doing that? How can you have an app with all sorts of random property keys? WHat would happen to the old properties?

Comment: @charlietfl Ideally the old keys should be deleted, replaced with the new value the user entered. Consider my usecase: The user is allowed to choose what headers to send using $http, which takes {headerName: headerValue}. I've realized this is impossible in templating alone, however, and will look for another solution

Comment: well that's not something you can do simply in the view so you would need to do some controller work to delete keys and add new ones. You can do it by creating new object that has properties like `key` and `value` then reconfigure the other object in controller after user is done with that row